# Can't retrieve str from mySqlite3

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7, mysql-python

Im trying to retrieve the latest versions of audit questions stored in table T3 of the hs_audit.sqlite.  I have tried multiple versions of the cur.exectute line but keep getting a result = None.  I'm new to sqlite so can anyone help me with the correct syntax.
If I execute the cur.execute line as follows

```
cur.execute("SELECT hvq1 FROM T3 WHERE audit_ver = 1")
```

and remove

```
con.text_factory = str
```

it works so i think the problem must be the use of variables in the sqlite command.

```
max_audit_ver = 1
audit_questions = ["hvq1", "hvq2", "hvq3", "hvq4", "hvq5"]

        count = 0
        for quest in audit_questions:
            con = sqlite3.connect("hs_audit.sqlite")
            con.text_factory = str
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT '%s' FROM T3 WHERE audit_ver = '%s'" %  (quest, max_audit_version))
            result = cur.fetchone()
            con.close()
            print "Question =%s" % (quest)
            print "Audit Version =%s" % (max_audit_version)
            print "The Count Is =%s" % (count)
            print "The return from the DB is =%s" % (result)
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind the synthax... `max_audit_version` and `max_audit_ver`

On the other hand, you should read [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), you will find some important note such as :

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()

# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```